# How to listen for presence on Laravel 5.4 backend?

Tags: events, broadcast, laravel-5.4, user-presence

Is there are some way to listen for presence channel **on backend**, not frontend? For example i want to execute some database operations when user joinin or leaving the channel?

Comment: which socket server, laravel-echo-server?

Comment: For example Pusher